# WCF: TCP endpoint incorrectly setup (Preamble 72)

Tags: c#, wcf

**Background**

I have a little service here that works as follows:

- A main process that manages app domains and recycles these every day.
- This process starts an appdomain, which spawns a WCF server. Let's say on port 12345 for the sake of argument. App domains can use a lot of memory.
- Clients run requests on the WCF server.
- Clients dispose their connection neatly. Regardless, recycling usually happens at 3 AM when no clients are active.

After the appdomain is recycled, the same port is re-used. That way, the clients still know which port to connect to. WCF servers are TCP based.

**Recycling**

Before the recycle takes place, the appdomain does some cleanup. Most importantly, the WCF servicehost is closed, which I expect to release the TCP-IP port. In more detail:

```
this.serviceHost.Close();
this.serviceHost = null;

// Some other cleanup

GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

After the cleanup, the appdomain is stopped and after a second started again. Stopping the app domain is quite straight forward:

```
try
{
    System.AppDomain.Unload(this.serviceDomain);
    this.serviceDomain = null;
}
catch (CannotUnloadAppDomainException err)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot unload app domain (attempt #{1}): {0}", err.Message, i + 1);
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
}
catch (AppDomainUnloadedException)
{
    this.serviceDomain = null;
}
```

**Problem**

Most of the times everything works fine. However, once every few weeks, recycling works fine, but the WCF server is unreachable. The error is:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: You have tried to create a channel to a service that 
does not support .NET Framing. It is possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint.
---> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Expected record type 'PreambleAck', found '72'.
```

What I find the weirdest thing here is that the WCF server seems to setup everything correctly. So, no exceptions are thrown when I call `serviceHost.Open();`, which is kinda what I would have expected when the socket was hijacked by another process.

What I'm looking for are possible root causes and things I can test to resolve this issue.

**Things I've tried**

The issue occurs on multiple machines, once every few weeks. Restarting the complete process resolves the issue.

- Google... obviously...
- First thing I've checked is if the port was hijacked by another process by checking `netstat -aonb`. (It seemed unlikely, but then again...) Netstat reports the port as being used by PID 4 (System). When the server works as expected, it reports the same thing.
- Any attempt to make a minimum test case has failed. I've attempted to recycle the appdomains every second, attempted to create long-running WCF calls to create lingering calls, even attempted to hijack the port using a TcpListener... no attempt so far has yielded the same error.
- Even not disposing the client / server also doesn't produce the same issues. Sure, I get errors, just not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Because of your question and information I realized that I was accidentally reusing a port and getting the same problem.